# ExpressJS Routing save params to Store.js

Tags: node.js, express

So i got this Store.js with the following two function:

```
select: function(type, id) {
        var list = memory[type];
        id = parseInt(id);
        list =  (list == undefined || list.length === 0)? undefined: list; // prevent []
        if (list != undefined && list.length > 0 && !isNaN(id)) {
            list = list.filter(function(element) {
                return element.id === id;
            });
            list =  (list.length === 0)? undefined: list[0]; // only return the 1 found element; prevent empty []
        }
        return getDeepObjectCopy(list); // may contain undefined, object or array;
    },


insert: function(type, element) {
    checkElement(element);
    if (element.id !== undefined) {
        throw new Error("element already has an .id value, but should not on insert!",e);
    }
    element.id = globalCounter();
    memory[type] = memory[type] || [];
    memory[type].push(getDeepObjectCopy(element));
    return element.id;
},
```

In my Videos.js i got this route. How can i POST data into this Store and how can i get it back?

```
videos.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        store.select(req)
        next();
    })
    .post(function(req,res,next) {
        store.insert(/json/ , {
            "title": req.param.name,
        })
        next();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

My answer was a bit off.

The way you're validating the requests and sending responses is a bit weird.

Your code should look more like this:

```
videos.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        if(!req.accepts('json')) {
            res.status(406).send('response of application/json only supported, please accept this');
        }
        res.send(getVideos());
    })
    .post(function(req,res,next) {
        if(!( /application\/json/.test(req.get('Content-Type')))) {
            res.status(415).send('wrong Content-Type');  // user has SEND the wrong type
            return;
        }

        const item = store.insert(/json/ , {
            "title": req.body.name,
        })
        res.send(item);
    });



insert: function(type, element) {
    checkElement(element);
    if (element.id !== undefined) {
        throw new Error("element already has an .id value, but should not on insert!",e);
    }
    element.id = globalCounter();
    memory[type] = memory[type] || [];
    return memory[type];
}
```

The validation of the content could go into middleware functions instead of right into the router controller callbacks. But this code helps to give you an idea of how requests should be handled.

Hope this helps

Comment: It helped, but how do i do the POST and get the saved Object back?

Comment: You mean, how to get a JSON repsponse on your post method?

Comment: @F0rce it helped because now it will not check for the proper request body type.

Comment: I know but know i got the Question, how can i save data via POSt and get data via GET into my Store.js